# Regexp: multiline-match anything between ( and );

Tags: regex

Here's my current setup:
[(image showing regexr-highlighted strings)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Osw9.png)

My regexp match is `Skript\.register(effect|expression|event|condition)\((.*)\)\;`

Basically, I want to match all methods from a source code file that start with `Skript.registerwhatever.(` and end with `);`, but the problem is the code can go multiline. If I change `(.*)` to `([\s\S]*)`, it completely wrecks and matches everything until the very last `);`.

Comment: You need a lexer and parser, not regex.

Comment: @leppie I'm using PHP.

Comment: Update your question with a live demo please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `lazy` quanitfier: `*?`

```
\(([\s\S]*?)\)
```

And if your string contains nested parenthesis:

```
(?'parens'\((?:[^\(]|\g'parens')*?\))
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks a lot! Your answer will be accepted in 7 minutes.

Comment: No it's not right. It doesn't match right part if there are nested parenthesis in place.

Comment: When would you have nested parenthesis in method definitions??

Comment: Check input string which OP provided.

Comment: Okay, answer edited

Comment: Weird, but it still matches with the nested parenthesis: https://i.gyazo.com/d23a5ad5973e5869e1e54b11191f25ff.png

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape parenthesis in regex because they are reserved symbols. Try `\(.*\)`

Comment: He did escape them `\((.*)\)`

Comment: You're right. My fault.